# Responsive images in a container not sizing properly

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm struggling trying to get images responsive in a container and it's driving me bonkers. I've looked at many different answers and the only one that seems to work is just making the image set to 100% of the width of the container (not using max-width), but I don't want to set the image at 100% all the time. Here's what I got:

HTML

```
<div id="interior_banner" class="title_pic">
<img src="assets/images/portraits_header-24.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img{max-width:100%;border:3px solid #fff}
.title_pic{text-align:center;margin:0 0 1em;}
```

Now setting the img to just width:100% works, but I really want this banner to flex only when it doesn't fit the container. I don't want it to size before then.

What am I missing? I know it's something.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: please upload some live code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With out a live demo this is a little harder but I'll give it my best go.

I think you're on the right path.  Currently isn't the image it's regular width?  It should shrink when the container gets small enough.  But if the container is bigger than the image the image won't scale up.

Or do you want the image to scale up?  More info would be awesome.

Comment: You know what? I think I just got it. I was trying to put it into JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/8HVXu/) for you for a live example when that example was working. I was using this code for a responsive footer (http://timothy-long.com/responsive-sticky-footer/) and the overall container was killing the image responsive-ness. -_- Thanks for being willing to help!

Comment: No problem.  Putting things into a jsfiddle is usually a good way to re-create the issue and possibly solve it while doing so.